# Shopify website is not working on Windows with Antivirus

Tags: windows, shopify, e-commerce, antivirus, namecheap

My shopify website is not working on the windows machine with the Antivirus.

https://krappletstore.com

I have purchased the domain from namecheap server and using the namecheap email service.

Kindly let me know, what is the issue behind this.

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. Do you have one? We're not here to debug anyone's website.

Comment: Thanks @JamesZ for commenting, I am not asking you to debug my website. I am just asking, if you know why it is happening to just on windows machine with antivirus?. Thanks

Comment: How could anyone know that based on what you've written here? So, you're asking them to go to your website and debug the problems there, aren't you?

Comment: I have shared the link just because, if anyone want to see, if it is really happening or not. That would be great if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: Do not use domain names that contain copyrighted names such as **apple store** or could be considered a phishing domain. You will need to select another domain name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Shopify-related. The problem is [your domain is blacklisted](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/krappletstore.com)

You have two options change the domain or pay for a cleanup. Exist multiple companies that can help you to remove the domain from the blacklist.

This question is not on the scope of StackOverflow, here is for programming thinks, you have other forums where this question will fit better.

I strongly recommend you read the guide about [how write your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)